# toString method in jquery? or something similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, return, tostring

ANSWER FOUND!

I'm reading an xml document and I am sending this to a function

```
$(data).find('colleges').attr('next')
```

that returns `discipline` and javascript is thinking it's a variable, can I some how get the attribute in the tag and have it return as a string like `'discipline'`

Is there a toString()-type method that I could add onto the selection?

```
$(data).find('colleges').attr('next').toString()
```

The issue I am having is that I am sending that to a function

```
createSelect( $(data).find('colleges').attr('next') )
```

but firebug is giving me an error saying that the value, discipline, is undefined? Why is javascript reading discipline as a var and not a string?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  You need to learn the fundamentals of variables and values.

Comment: i think he wants the tag name as as string? hard to tell

Comment: Please post the value referenced by `data` so we can better see what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this...

```
$(data).find('colleges')
```

...doesn't find any matches ( `<colleges>...</colleges>` ), then this...

```
.attr('next')
```

...will return `undefined`.

The first thing you should do is test to see if the `.find()` found anything.

```
alert( $(data).find('colleges').length );
```

If the `alert` gives you `0`, then there were no matches, and you'll have to inspect your `data` to see if it contains what you expect.

Comment: It returns discipline but js is reading that as a variable and not a string to be passed into a function.

Comment: @Phil: Why do you think javascript thinks it's a variable? What do you get if you do `alert( typeof $(data).find('colleges').attr('next') )`?

Comment: @Phil - why can you say `js is reading that as a variable and not a string` ? `.attr()` always return a string - [check docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr)- look fot the `Returns: String`

Comment: @Phil: I just saw your update. I'm guessing that the `createSelect` method you're calling has a *parameter* named `discipline`, and you're passing `undefined` to it. Please do what I suggested in my answer and let me know the result.

Comment: @patrick dw - you hit the spot! @Phil - `discipline` is undefined because maybe `$(data).find('colleges')` did not find a match or if it did, `.attr('next')` is `undefined`.

Comment: Gosh darn it. It returns 0 - gosh darn it. I apologize, firebug through me off. Thank you very much Patrick dw.

Answer (score 3):

The `attr` function returns a string, which you can put into a variable.